# Why does a Django Postgres Migration Altering field to DurationField causes an error?

Tags: django, postgresql

When running migrations with the postgres `DATABASE_ENGINE` I am getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type numeric to interval
LINE 1: ...R COLUMN "duration" TYPE interval USING "duration"::interval
```

when the migration alters a field from a `DecimalField`

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='entry',
        name='duration',
        field=models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I would add an extra column, write a manual data migration, then remove the original column, and rename the new one to the old. It looks like a decimal can not be converted to an interval directly.

Comment: Agreed. In my case, as retention of prior data was not needed I just squashed the migrations and an interval was created from the start.